# MySQL query returns non-object?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing code for a user to update his password on a user account system.

This is the portion of code I am referring to:

```
$checker = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT userid FROM tbl_user WHERE userpassword = '".md5($current)."'");
//echo "SELECT userid FROM tbl_user WHERE userpassword = '".md5($current)."'";
if ($checker == $_SESSION['exp_user']['userid']) {$check = true;} else {$check = false;}
```

For some reason, `$checker` is returning an object array rather than an object itself.

Doing a `print_r($checker)` produces this:

```
mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )
```

Any ideas on what I should be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't return an "object array", just an object. The class of the object is `mysqli_result` (as expected) and it got some public fields like `num_rows` as seen on [the manual of the MySQLi_Result class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php). If you want to read data from the result set you still have to use fetch methods like [mysqli_result::fetch_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), even if you result set contains only one row and one column.